# Symfony2 UrlGenerator in tests

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, symfony-2.3

I'm trying to achieve generated routes in my functional tests. I want them to be generated dynamically,preferably by name, but I cannot find a proper way how to do it. Point me please.

A simple test:

```
  public function testIndex()
    {
        // I have service container
        $container = $this->client->getContainer();
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', helper_function("route_name", $params));
        $heading = $crawler->filter('h1')->eq(0)->text();
        $this->assertEquals('Application list', $heading);
    }
```

What that `helper_function()` should be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have access to service container you can get `router` (which by default will return `Symfony\Component\Routing`) service and call [generate](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Routing/Router.html#method_generate) method on it.

```
$route = $container->get('router')->generate($routeName, $params);
```

Answer (score 3):

In the setup of the WebTestCase class you can take an instance of the router component then use it as usually.

As Example:

```
 class AcmeDemoTestCase extends WebTestCase


    protected $router;


        protected function setUp()
    {
        ........
        $this->client = static::createClient();
        $this->router = $this->client->getContainer()->get('router');
         .....
     }


         public function testIndex()
        {
        $crawler = $this->client->request('GET', $this->router->generate($routeName, $params););

       }
```

Hope this help